# Scheduling python script to run in open cmd window on EC2

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, amazon-ec2

I have a python script that I  want to schedule the running of, on an EC2 server. I created a .bat file with the contents:

```
cd "C:\python27\subdirectory"
python myscript.py
```

When I run this script locally, it opens up cmd.exe and works fine. When I run on my EC2 instance, it does nothing at all (on a Windows Server 2012 instance).

Is there a better way to schedule to script to run? Ideally this would be in an open cmd/PS window so I can check the output.

Comment: When you say running locally, do you mean on your own machine?  Does your EC2 instance have python installed?  Try to ssh into the instance and running the `.bat` file and see if it works.

Comment: Yep by locally I mean my own machine. I believe I have replicated my python setup on the EC2 instance in line with my machine. I'm a novice so don't quite follow 'ssh into the instance' - is there a link I can read up on for this?

Comment: Here's the Wikipedia page for [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). Here's EC2's [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-ssh.html) about sshing into your instance. Basically it's a secure way to open up a terminal to a remote server.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been playing around with it today and as a novice, I think my problem has evolved into a different one. I cant seem to connect through putty to the instance (it times out). I think this is as the server isn't configured to accept SSH. However I think the reason I can't run the bat file is that running .bats through Remote Desktop (how I access the server) is not allowed without installing a specific role. I'm making slow progress but progress nonetheless I think.

Comment: To clarify some confusion... You are working on a Windows instance. Therefore, ssh is not required -- use RDP instead to access the instance (as you are probably already doing). The first question is whether Python is working on your Windows instance. Try opening a CMD window, typing "python" and seeing whether it starts.